# Mobile Site - Empty area on the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a mobile website and I'm facing an empty area on the right (when I scroll the page to the left), as you can see below:

1 - Normal page:

[image]

2 - Scrolling page to the left:

[image]

All the page content is inside of "container" id. The site is divided by 5 divs, called "secao".

```
body{
    background-color: #323031;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Planer;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
}

#container{
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}

.secao{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If I change .secao CSS inserting border: 1px solid red, I got it:

[image]

Here you can find the website: http://www.camona.com.br/ideaos/site/laboratorio/mobile/

Could you please help me to find a solution to this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks like your FB like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZlZo.png) iframe is increasing the page width. There may be more things like this increasing the width.

Comment: I follow your suggestion and realized that "CAMONA" div was increasing the page width. Thanks!

Comment: @ALANGULARTE Sorry about the lack of a response, but sometimes going through all your page elements and inspecting their widths is the best thing to do to fix these types of errors

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, putting

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in the `<head>` section should do the trick. You can read more about it if you wish here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html